# PHPunit and getopt

Tags: phpunit

I'm trying to test a component that uses a third party library which makes use of getopt to retrieve command line arguments.

Is there any way I can get this working within PHPunit?

I've tried inserting this prior to the component call:

```
$args = explode( ' ', 'scriptName -q staging_to_xxx -w 250 -c 500' );
$_SERVER['argv'] = $args;
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a php.ini setting, `register_argc_argv=false` to allow you to set the argv and argc globals. It appears that getopt uses the global variables, meaning that this approach will work.

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['argv']=array(
    'argv_test.php',
    '-a999',
    '-b',
    );
$GLOBALS['argc']=count($argv);
var_export(getopt("a:b"));
?>
```

If you've called that script 'argv_test.php', then first run as normal:

```
$ php  argv_test.php -a777 -b
array (
  'a' => '777',
  'b' => false,
)
```

Then run by overriding the ini setting:

```
$ php -d register_argc_argv=false argv_test.php
array (
  'a' => '999',
  'b' => false,
)
```

Comment: I got here via a Google search on the same subject, and this doesn't work with the PHPUnit command-line test runner. It sets php.ini settings using ini_set(), which doesn't work for this purpose; the setting apparently needs to be set before the interpreter is fired up.

Comment: @MaxCrowe Which version of php, and which version of phpUnit?

Comment: This is PHP 5.3.29 and PHPUnit 4.6.